# What is the determiner for Ostern?

Tags: gender, determiners

These holidays have the following determiners/gender:

- das Weihnachten
- der Silvester
- der Karfreitag
- der Ostersonntag
- der Ostermontag

But **what is the determiner/gender for Ostern?**

There's no information on http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Ostern&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ostern

Comment: Constructions where it matters tend to be avoided. Same with _Weihnachten_ and _Silvester_, in spite of what you say in your question.

Comment: Also possible: [**das** Silvester](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Silvester_Tag_Jahresende), which is IMHO (which might be biased) the more common gender for that holiday (but see chirlu's comment).

Comment: @Loong♦ Or [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ostern), @matthias: "der Silvester" sounds like the [guy](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvester_I.)

Comment: @ospalh Yes, that's true, but the Duden entry I linked to explicitly describes the holiday and allows both the neuter and masculine form. They have a separate entry for the name.

Comment: @Carsten-S, why did you remove all the information to the post and replace it with "What's up with that?"...

Comment: @alvas, your question was correctly closed, because you failed to consult a dictionary. (Leo is not a dictionary.) However, the classification as neutrum that a dictionary will give you tells only half of the story, as you can see from the very good answer. I did not want to let that answer leave orphaned, because I was actually just wondering myself why it is "frohe Ostern". (I am German.)

Comment: @alvas, since you don't agree: Fine, it's your question.

Comment: I understand that the dictionary tells half the story but i think if you edit the question to the post you wrote, it will attract quite a lot of downvotes and it will be quite a disaster since it won't fit the "how to ask a question" standards on stackexchange =) I hope you understand the predicament.

Comment: @alvas, the question is closed anyway, I was trying to get it reopened. But you are right, it was probably the wrong way to ask the question.

Comment: It is »**die** Weihnachten« because it is a plural word. It comes from »*zu wihen nahten*« which is in modern German »*zu den geweihten Nächten*« and in english »*at the sanctified nights*«. Also »die Ostern« are plural.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Ostern* and *Weihnachten* are usually perceived as **plurals** (hence *die*), probably due to the characteristic *n* ending, and at least for the latter rightly so.

Consider the respective seasonal greetings, *Frohe Ostern!* and *Frohe Weihnachten!* – it’s never *frohe**r*** and rarely *frohe**s*** (also *weiße ~* for snow). The definite article *der/die/das* is hardly ever used directly with holidays that do not end with *Tag* (e.g. *der Mutter-/Vater-/Maifeiertag* or *Nacht* as in *die Weihnacht*), but the indefinite article *ein+* and pronouns sometimes occur, e.g. *diese/dieses Weihnachten/Ostern verbringe ich bei meinen Eltern* (i.e. this year). **Neuter** sounds a bit more natural in this case than with adjectives (and without article), but I would still expect the gender-less plural.

With DET + ADJ + multi-day festivity, as pointed out in the comments, *das* becomes more common, e.g. *das orthodoxe Ostern*. One may assume that the semantic difference between singular *Osterfest* and plural *Ostertage*, which both can be substituted by *Ostern*, can be decisive.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the plural nature of O. and W. But nevertheless, there are cases where the definite singular article is the better choice. From a quick Google search: "Das perfekte Weihnachten" (a movie), "Das erste Weihnachten" (a book), "Ich war zehn Jahre alt, als wir 1989 das erste Weihnachten in Freiheit feierten.", "Wenn das erste Weihnachten mit Kind vor der Tür steht, versuchen Eltern alles möglichst perfekt zu gestalten.".

Comment: @Matthias, würden Deine Beispiele nicht der pluralen Natur von Weihnachten wiedersprechen? In der Schweiz wäre es übrigens "die erste Weihnacht", aber "die letzten Ostern".

Comment: @RalphM.Rickenbach Ja eben. Ich wollte ja auch sagen: der Hinweis auf den Plural ist gut, aber in manchen Verwendungen ist es doch klar ein Singular. - "Die erste Weihnacht" könnte man bei uns auch noch sagen, glaube ich. Es klänge nur etwas feierlich-altmodisch. "Die letzten Ostern" habe ich hingegen noch nicht gehört.

Comment: @Matthias I have added a paragraph to mention such phrases.

Comment: @RalphM.Rickenbach: Althochdeutsch sprach man von dem Fest »zu wihen nahten«, was in modernem Deutsch »zu den geweihten Nächten« heißt. Aus diesem Dativ-Plural wurden dann »die Weihnachten«. Es waren damals (und sind vielerorts auch heute noch immer) mehrere Nächte, die zusammen die Weihnachten bilden. Dass man heute dieses Pluralwort manchmal fälschlicherweise im Singular verwendet, hängt vermutlich damit zusammen, dass in manchen Gegenden dieses Fest auf nur einen Tag verkürzt wurde.

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Für dieses Eintages-Fest gibt es aber den Begriff »Heilige Nacht«, oder man kann auch den Singular von "Weihnachten« verwenden, und das ist dann »die Weihnacht« (ohne Pluralsuffix -en)